# Как сохранить положение ToggleButton?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, button, save

Как сохранить положение ToggleButton, при удаление из оперативной памяти телефона?

То есть когда я нажимаю на ToggleButton и ухожу из приложения, а после закрываю все запущенные приложения, то он должен сохранить положение ToggleButton при последующем входе в приложение.

Вот на всякий случай код:

```
ToggleButton toggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.ToggleButton);
        toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
                    onRestart();
                } else {
                    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
                    onRestart();
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

Для таких вещей есть [SharedPreference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences).

Флоу будет примерно такой:

- Запускаете приложение
- Где-нибудь в `onCreate()` Activity чекаете префы
- Если там `null` то ставите тогл в состояние по умолчанию. В противном случае берете значение оттуда.
- При любом изменении состояния тогла записываете его в префы.

Здесь есть [Урок по SharedPreference](https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/73-urok-33-hranenie-dannyh-preferences.html).

Comment: Ок, флоу я понял. Я новичок и многое не понимаю. Я просто не знаю как реализовать состояние togglebutton в каком либо положении. Мне надо чтобы он включал и выключал тёмную тему

Comment: Вопрос о включении и выключении темной темы это намного более сложный вопрос. Вам нужно вызвать изменнеия конфигурации всего приложения. Заменить всю разметку и т.д.

Comment: А как это сделать? Можете помочь в реализации?